# Google AdWord Implementation iOS - stop to print log on console

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-ads-api

I have Implemented successfully **Google AdWord** in my project.
but having one small **query**.

Lets see first what I did.

I've add some accounts to **AdWord conversion** tracking with this method

```
[ACTAutomatedUsageTracker enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID:@"MY_ID"];
[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:@"MY_ID" label:@"MY_LABEL" value:@"MY_VALUE" isRepeatable:NO];
```

It was working fine and **Ping** send successfully to server.
with +ve response.

Log:

> 2015-06-02 11:10:26.660 AppName[670:16604]  ACTAutomatedUsageReporterPrivate: sending ping: https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/MY_ID/?appversion=1.5&auto=1&bundleid=My_Project_ID&lat=0&osversion=8.3&rdid=9E624D3A-CD34-4BF6-BE97-2A37E2FA1854&sdkversion=ct-sdk-i-v3.2.0&timestamp=1433225711.412397&usage_tracking_enabled=1.

and

> 2015-06-02 11:10:27.188 AppName[670:16604]  ping successful.

But it printed some log on console.

#### I don't want to display above log on my console. Because it was for one account and I reported total 15 account. so console report is too large.

***If Any one used it and handle this requirement then please share your expert experience with me. Thanks.***